# simple_cov: how to include tests of engine to the report?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, code-coverage

Our rails application is using an engine and build upon customer projects. The engine itself is not executable as a standalone program. Using simple_cov works just fine for the customer projects. However, launching all tests (customer and engine) causes rake to abort after performing all of them and writing the coverage report for the customer project. Basicly everthing works but writing the coverage report for the engine.

The engine is stored in an external folder next to the customer project. Used testing suite is rspec

So, is there a way to include the engine in the SimpleCov config?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you requiring simplecov? I had a similar problem, not with an engine, but rather trying to cover all tests in a "non-standard" rails application with a services architecture. Most of the files (even files in lib/ and models/) were not loaded. The way I solved that was to require simple_cov in "config/environments/test.rb". Hope that helps!